# Where to get latest Google Cloud Storage Client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a GAE app that uses Google Cloud Storage. On development machine I'm getting following WARNING when trying to use Storage API:

```
WARNING: Class com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper 
loaded from target/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.3.2.jar 
has a dependency on class com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.ExceptionHandler 
loaded from (target/webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.3.2.jar <no signer certificates>), 
which is not part of App Engine's supported API.
You are strongly discouraged from using this class - your app may 
stop working in production at any moment.
```

What should I do? Does it mean that my version of GCS client is outdated?

I'm using version 0.3.2, it's a latest that I can find in Maven ([see](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client)). [Official site](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/downloads/list) have a different naming scheme, and latest version is r127, but I cannot find this version in Maven.
Is there any other (unofficial?) repo for GCS client library?

Answer (score 1):

I was concerned by the log messages in my development server as well. I looked up the source for ExceptionHandler, and I saw the log message on the latest commit (r120) said:

> Remove the use of @AppEngineInternal
>   as dev appserver complains about it.

Here's a [link to it](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/ExceptionHandler.java?spec=svn120&r=120). It seems like the dev server just doesn't like the annotation, and no functionality was changed with the commit.

Comment: Thank you for investigation. Hope they will fix it in a future release (and deploy a correct version to a repo)

Answer (score 0):

[A fix](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/detail?r=120) for this was committed to the library. The fix is what [d2013](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730699/d2013) suggested.

I just tested with [version 0.3.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine.tools/appengine-gcs-client/0.3.3) and can confirm that upgrading the dependency will resolve the issue.